# Submit value from jade template without refresh

Tags: node.js, pug

I am a newbie in node.js. Just need a little bit of clarification here. I am using jade as the view engine. Other than normal form submit and ajax technology, is there any other way to submit date from a jade template in node?

Thanks

Comment: [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) can be used for data transfer. See the modules you can use :https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-ws-ajax

Comment: The important question: Why? What are you trying to do, which you can't achieve with ajax? You can obviously use web sockets, as the answers say, but you only really need it if you want asynchronous real time communication.

Comment: Just wanted to know the norms. Do they use AJAX or do they have anything of their own built-in. As nodejs is already built on JS platform so I thought there may be some other way for the request/response method. Anyways, thanks to all of you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) is one other method, although it's not tied to Jade specifically (can also be used from plain HTML).

Comment: Socket.io gracefully degrades from WebSockets to Flash, Ajax, IFrames etc. Works in modern browsers and mobile devices. Oh Yeah!

Answer (score 1):

Heck, you could even go 1999 and write a 1x1px transparent `<img>` with a src url containing GET parameters picked up by another route. If you are going to all that trouble, why are you not just using ajax again?